# ImportError: No module named Blender

Tags: python, blender

I worked with Blender 2.49 and in my script I used `from Blender import *`. But now I'm upgrading my code to Blender 2.74 and when I run appears this error *No module named Blender*. There have been changes to call Blender module in version 2.74?

Comment: Is your path to Blender 2.74 the same as for Blender 2.49?

Comment: Try install afer uninstall.`pip uninstall blender` then `pip install blender` then `from Blender import.....`.

Comment: @boardrider. My path to Blender 2.74 is different to Blender 2.49.

Comment: So, there's your answer. Follow @HelloNewWorld suggestion and you should be able to use the Blender 2.74 module.

Answer (score 3):

From 2.50 blender started using python 3.x and the python api was completely changed. From 2.63 bmesh (supporting n-gons) was added which changed the way mesh editing was done.

You may want to start with some [python 2 to 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) as some parts of your script may need changes to work in python 3.x.

You can find the new [api reference online](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/) and I would suggest you start with the quickstart and overview listed on that page, maybe even experiment with the sample script templates that you can find in blender's text editor.

Once you have an idea of the new python api take a go at re-doing your script. You will also find better help for blender specific python scripting at [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I read about that. I changed my code to support python 3.X but I think this problem is about Blender syntax, and not Python. Thanks for your comment, I going to search more about this.

Comment: The python3 changes needed should be small, depending on your code, the main point is the api change in blender 2.50, all scripts from 2.49 fail in blender >2.50, that is why I suggest getting familiar with the new api then go back to your script.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import bpy
```

You can find the Blender 2.74 API documentation here:

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/info_quickstart.html